# Logback programmatic configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I am configuring logback programmatically. I am also using Spring Boot, and I would like to set the logs location in application.properties.  I know in XML there is a springProperty tag, where is this in the Java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in spring-boot you can define logging config in application.properties

```
logging.path = /path/to/folder/log
```

logfile would then be named spring.log

> [Using logging.path] Writes spring.log to the specified directory.
>   Names can ?be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

Here: is nice article about [logging](https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/) with springboot